# How to decrypt Java AES on Nodejs

Tags: java, node.js, encryption

I have the following code on Java that decrypts AES encryption and I need to do the same on Node.js

```
private static SecretKeySpec secretKey;
private static byte[] key;

public static void setKey(String myKey) {
    MessageDigest sha = null;
    try {
        key = myKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
        sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        key = sha.digest(key);
        key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16);
        secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");


    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

 public static String decrypt(String strToDecrypt, String secret) 
{
    try
    {
        setKey(secret);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(strToDecrypt)));
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println("Error while decrypting: " + e.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
```

I have tried using Crypt under the following code, but it doesn't give me the same results

```
  var aesDecrypt = (text, password, bit) => {
  var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-' + bit + '-ecb', password, Buffer.alloc(0));
  decipher.setAutoPadding(false);
  return Buffer.concat([
    decipher.update(text, 'base64'),
    decipher.final()
   ]).toString();
  };
```

How could I mimick that Java code from above into Node.js?

Comment: This might help - https://gist.github.com/ericchen/3081970

Comment: Already tried that, it throws errors

Comment: You're not using the same key. In Java you are hashing the string with SHA1, in node you're not.

Comment: So how can that be done in Node.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As James says, the Java code is hashing (and truncating) the password to form the key. Also it *does* use standard padding. The following works for *ASCII* data:

```
const crypto = require ('crypto');
const mydecrypt = (pw,ctx) => {
    var h = crypto.createHash('sha1'); h.update(pw,'utf8'); var k = h.digest().slice(0,16);
    var d = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-128-ecb', k, Buffer.alloc(0)); 
    return Buffer.concat([d.update(ctx,'base64'), d.final()]) .toString();
}
console.log(mydecrypt('password','ks7qtmk7kt5riV/Qyy3glQ=='));

->
testdata
```

It may not work for non-ASCII data. Java `new String(byte[])` uses a JVM-dependent encoding which may be UTF8 or may be something different depending on your platform, build, and environment, none of which you described. OTOH nodejs `Buffer.toString()` always uses UTF8. You may need to change it to `toString(somethingelse)` to match the Java.

---

If this 'password' is truly a password, i.e. chosen or even remembered by one or more human(s), using a simple hash of it is **very weak** and will probably be broken if used for anything not utterly trivial; you should use a [Password-Based Key Derivation Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) designed for the purpose by someone competent, like older (PKCS5) PBKDF2 or newer bcrypt, scrypt, or argon2. However, that's not a programming question and is offtopic here; it has been discussed many times and at length on https://crypto.stackexchange.com and https://security.stackexchange.com .